# jquery validation form before submit on multiple section?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to use it and the validation plugin (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js) (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js)
to create a single form with multiple sections for different sections. Right now I have it where there are multiple section and the "Next" button switches to the next section.

The problem I'm having is that when I finally submit on the last page, the form validates properly but if there are errors on the other page the user isn't notified, and validation really only happens once "submit" is clicked.

How would I validate each individually when I click "Next"? I don't really want to create multiple forms.
below is the code.

```
<form  method="POST" id="myform">
    <section class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class=""></div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">First Name</label> <input
                        type="text" class="form-control" id="field" name="firstName">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Last Name</label> <input
                        type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2"
                        name="lastName">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputName2">Email Id</label> <input
                        type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2"
                        name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Phone No</label> <input
                        class="form-control" type="text" name="mobileNumber">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</form>

<script>
     $(".button-next-pre")
        .click(
                function() {
                    $("#svg_form_time rect").css("fill", active_color);
                    $("#svg_form_time circle")
                            .css("fill", active_color);
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
                    if (id == "next") {
                        $("#prev").removeClass("disabled");
                        if (child >= length) {

                            $(this).addClass("disabled");
                            $('#submit').removeClass("disabled");
                        }
                        if (child <= length) {
                            child++;
                        }
                    } else if (id == "prev") {
                        $("#next").removeClass("disabled");
                        $('#submit').addClass("disabled");
                        if (child <= 2) {
                            $(this).addClass("disabled");
                        }
                        if (child > 1) {
                            child--;
                        }
                    }
                    var circle_child = child + 1;
                    $(
                            "#svg_form_time rect:nth-of-type(n + "
                                    + child + ")").css("fill",
                            base_color);
                    $(
                            "#svg_form_time circle:nth-of-type(n + "
                                    + circle_child + ")").css("fill",
                            base_color);
                    var currentSection = $("section:nth-of-type("
                            + child + ")");
                    currentSection.fadeIn();
                    currentSection.css('transform', 'translateX(0)');
                    currentSection.prevAll('section').css('transform',
                            'translateX(-100px)');
                    currentSection.nextAll('section').css('transform',
                            'translateX(100px)');
                    $('section').not(currentSection).hide();
                });
         </script>

    <script>
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
debug: true,
success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate( {
rules: {
    firstName: {
    required: true,
    normalizer: function( value ) {

        return $.trim( value );
    }
    },
    lastName: {
    required: true,
    normalizer: function( value ) {

        return $.trim( value );
    }
    }
    
}

} );
    .....
</script>
```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with almost the same version of that validation plugin.  http://jsfiddle.net/amwmedia/sw87W/

Comment: my question is not about the version but i want to do validation when clicking on the next button before submitting the form

Comment: Creating or editing a jsfiddle is a great way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate single element using code below.

```
var validator = $( "#myform" ).validate();
validator.element( "#myselect" );
```

For documentation https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/

Answer (score 0):

It had lots of problems in the condition parts which I changed and you can see what the problem was by differentiating two functions.

```
if (id == "next") {
  console.log("next button is checked");
  console.log("child", child);
  console.log("length", length);
  $("#prev").removeClass("disabled");

  if (child == length) {
    console.log("child", child);
    if (
      $("input[name=radio-group11]:checked").length > 0 &&
      $("input[name=radio-group12]:checked").length > 0 &&
      $("input[name=radio-group13]:checked").length > 0 &&
      $("input[name=radio-group14]:checked").length > 0 &&
      $("input[name=radio-group15]:checked").length > 0
    ) {
      document.getElementById("next").innerHTML = "نتیجه ی نهایی";
      $(this).addClass("disabled");
      $("#submit").removeClass("disabled");
      child++;
      document.getElementById("submit").hidden = true;
      Score_Calculation();
    } else {
      alert("لطفا به تمامی سوالات پاسخ دهید.");
    }
  }
  if (child == length - 1) {
    if (
      $("input[name=radio-group6]:checked").length > 0 &&
      $("input[name=radio-group7]:checked").length > 0 &&
      $("input[name=radio-group8]:checked").length > 0 &&
      $("input[name=radio-group9]:checked").length > 0 &&
      $("input[name=radio-group10]:checked").length > 0
    ) {
      document.getElementById("next").innerHTML = "بعدی";
      child++;
      document.getElementById("next").innerHTML = "نتیجه ی نهایی";
    } else {
      alert("لطفا به تمامی سوالات پاسخ دهید.");
    }
  } else if (child < length) {
    if (child == 2) {
      if (
        $("input[name=radio-group1]:checked").length > 0 &&
        $("input[name=radio-group2]:checked").length > 0 &&
        $("input[name=radio-group3]:checked").length > 0 &&
        $("input[name=radio-group4]:checked").length > 0 &&
        $("input[name=radio-group5]:checked").length > 0
      ) {
        document.getElementById("next").innerHTML = "بعدی";
        child++;
      } else {
        alert("لطفا به تمامی سوالات پاسخ دهید.");
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById("next").innerHTML = "بعدی";
      child++;
    }
  }
}
```